# Fetching two different APIS on two differents routes originating from same route in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

So far I implemented a route (url "/") that fetches all data from an API (5000 objects) and shows for each of those an own card (m-ui).

When I click on a button in one of those card, I am forwarded to another route ("/card/id) which shows specific properties of the respective card

Going back to ("/"), I would like to implement that when I click on another button in the card, I get forwarded to a route ("/post/id") which also shows specific data, but from another API.

However, so far I couldn't manage to fetch any data from that new API and when I click on mentioned button, I just get a blank page and a console which doesn't do anything.

Displayed how I want the routing to work in a diagramm, it would look like his:

API A --> API A/id
API A --> API B/id

In hope this was comprehensible, I would appreciate any hint.
Maybe I am missing some basic functionality of routes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any react router library should provide you with a param value that you can use to fetch the api endpoint you need.

- your / is fetching all cards
- /card/:id route should match a component that will have the id available for you , for example if you are using react router you can get the id you need
  https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

also from the react router documentation

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
// here you can make your API call to get the card by id 
function BlogPost() {
  let { slug } = useParams();
  return <div>Now showing post {slug}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/blog/:slug">
        <BlogPost />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  node
);

}
```